# Java HashMap only returning last element of list

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, return

I'm working on a 2D game, and I'm using LWJGL and the Slick-Util library to help. There's nothing too complicated about it and I've programmed much more difficult things before. However, I've encountered a very odd problem with HashMap / Map return values. This is my code regarding the HashMap:

```
    public Map<String, Texture> textures;

    public void loadTextures()
    {
        textures = new HashMap<String, Texture>();

        textures.put("char_up", main.loadTextureFrom("character/character_up.png"));
        textures.put("char_down", main.loadTextureFrom("character/character_down.png"));
        textures.put("char_right", main.loadTextureFrom("character/character_right.png"));
        textures.put("char_left", main.loadTextureFrom("character/character_left.png"));
    }
```

However, anytime I use textures.get(frameHere), it ALWAYS returns the LAST item I put for the HashMap, so if my last item was "char_right", it will ALWAYS return the char_right texture, even if I called something like textures.get("char_up"). I tried setting character positions by loading another instance of the texture every time the character changed directions, and it worked perfectly. Meaning, the problem isn't the texture loader or the way I'm getting textures as a value into my HashMap.

This is pretty frustrating and I'm at a huge loss as to what I might be messing up here. Maybe there is something incredibly simple that I'm missing, because I've done this in Java before without a problem, but even with comparison everything looks 100% fine. Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

Here is my loadTextureFrom() method:

```
public Texture loadTextureFrom(String path)
{
    try
    {
        return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/textures/" + path)));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: what does main.loadTextureFrom() do?? Can you post the code??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516549/bad-idea-to-use-string-key-in-hashmap

Comment: Could it be that loadTextureFrom is the culprit?

Comment: Just posted the loadTextureFrom() method. It shouldn't be the problem, I've had it return different textures when not using the HashMap, but since it's requested I edited the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A common misconception about collections including HashMap, is when adding or putting a key/value/element you are placing a copy of that element.  Instead you are placing a copy of the reference to the element.

The problem you describe is only really possible if the `main.loadTextureFrom` is returning the same image each time.  This would work if you used the image before calling this method again, but if you want to save the image, you will need to save a copy of it.

Comment: Appreciate the input! However, in my post I explained that I tried loading the textures from scratch without using the dictionary, and it worked fine. Meaning, the problem isn't the method. The method itself is fine, I've changed the character's directions just fine and it has returned the correct textures. It's only when I attempt to get it from the HashMap. Also, I said that it doesn't return the SAME element, it always returns the LAST element. So if char_up is the last element, it returns char_up. If the last element is char_down, it returns char_down.

Comment: Never the less, the behaviour you describe can only mean you are updating the same value object each time.  HashMap has been used and tested by millions of developers for fifteen years.

Comment: Yeah I know. I've used it a ton of times like this and never had a problem. I expected to get a problem like, it returning the same value over and over again but instead it only returns the last value. I've never heard of this before.

Comment: I posted the loadTextureFrom() method, so you can see it's really just the same as any other. Nothing special or different about it.

Comment: I suggest you print the `System.identityObject(texture)` for each object to check they are all different.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your image loader returns the same object each time it is called, instead of creating a new object. Java Maps only store references to objects, they do not copy them by value.

**Make sure to create a new Image object for each new load.**